# How to resolve this error of October CMS ?

Tags: php, laravel, octobercms

In OctoberCMS i installed Rainlab.Forum plugin after that the CMS of October is giving me error . The error is actually in this line

```
if ($channel) {
        $channel->setUrl($this->channelPage, $this->controller);
}
```

I am a newbie in PHP and Laravel , so i am facing terrible problems [This Is Picture of The Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5QthM.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I was alo having this issue. You have to remove a rouge bracket in

```
/plugins/rainlab/forum/components/Topic.php around line 172
```

**See image:**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This has been fixed in v1.0.18 by this commit https://github.com/rainlab/forum-plugin/commit/f15d16c69774eaba9aecd37629abdea5950352b2

You just need to update your OctoberCMS website via the backend interface or the command line :
`php artisan october:update`